Leftover wax after salat in islam
I tried to wax and saw some leftover residue but while I tried to remove it my skin started to hurt and burn,so i left it. After salat i find some residue left. Am I suppose to try and get it off even tho the skin burns and repeat salat? I even tried using hot water or olive oil, it didnt work.
